# Questions about the nested interval principle

Tags: analysis

I am a little confused by the nested interval principle, and want to know if the following statement is valid, and if not, where the mistake is.

Suppose we know that $0$ has the property P, and that $\forall a \in[0,2^{-n}] \subset \Bbb R$ has property P if and only if $\forall b \in[0,2^{-(n+1)}]\subset \Bbb R $  also has the property P, with  $n\in \Bbb N$

Then is it true that every real number in interval $[0,1] \subset \Bbb R$ has property P?  My idea is to proove that $\forall a \in[0,1]$has property P $\iff \forall a \in[0,\frac{1}{2}]=[0,1]\cap[0,\frac{1}{2}]$and therefore $\iff \forall a \in \bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}[0,2^{-n}]$ has property P

and then we use the nested interval principle to show that $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}[0,2^{-n}]=0$. And because $0$ has the property P, so that every real number in interval $[0,1]$ has property P.
Any help or hint will be much appreciated!!